# Node with SQL Server (Microsoft) connection to database

Tags: sql-server, node.js, sockets, tcp

I need t o provide the SQL connection (using the library called mssql) for modules, so I provide the code like this:

```
var config = {
    server: "149.xxx.xx.x",
    database: "Database",
    user: "User",
    password: "Password",
    connectionTimeout: 300000,
    requestTimeout: 300000,
    pool: {
        idleTimeoutMillis: 300000,
        max: 100
    }
};

function getEmp() {
    var connection = new sql.Connection(config);
    var req = new sql.Request(connection);

    connection.connect(function (error) {
        if(error) {
            console.log(error);
            return;
        }
        req.query('Procedure', function(err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                console.log(data);
            }
            connection.close();
        });
    });
}

getEmp();`
```

and I receive the error:

```
 { ConnectionError: Failed to connect to 149.xxx.xx.x:1433 - connect
ETIMEDOUT 149.xxx.xx.x:1433 at Connection.<anonymous>
(/Users/xx/Learning/NodeJS/srv-express/node_modules/mssql/lib/tedious.js:353:25)
at Connection.g (events.js:292:16) at emitOne (events.js:96:13) at
Connection.emit (events.js:188:7) at Connection.socketError
(/Users/xx/Learning/NodeJS/srv-express/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:791:12)
at Socket.<anonymous>
(/Users/xx/Learning/NodeJS/srv-express/node_modules/tedious/lib/connection.js:33:15)
at emitOne (events.js:96:13) at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7) at
emitErrorNT (net.js:1277:8) at _combinedTickCallback
(internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)


name: 'ConnectionError',   message: 'Failed to connect to
49.xxx.xx.x:1433 - connect ETIMEDOUT 149.xxx.xx.x:1433',   code: 'ESOCKET' }
```

For sure the data are correct- DataGrip is connecting fine here.

I found at google the similar problem, the problem was Disabled TCP/IP. I checked this one and it's Enabled with this port 1443.

> The TCP/IP, Named Pipes and Shared Memory is Enabled.
>
> TCP Dynamic Ports: 1443 TCP Port: empty

Comment: to what port do you try to connect, 1433 or 1443?

Comment: The post is default port 1433, now I see it was bad. On PORT: 1443, I have the error:
`{ ConnectionError: Login failed for user 'User'.`

`name: 'ConnectionError',
  message: 'Login failed for user \'User\'.',
  code: 'ELOGIN' }`

Comment: This means at least the port is correct, you reached the server, but have another problem. Check sql server errorlog to find out the exact reason of "login failed"

Comment: I check the logs:

`Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38.`
`Login failed for user 'User'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'Database Name'. [CLIENT: MYIP]`

Comment: is the 'Database Name' online?

Comment: What means online? When I login in SQL Server or DataGrip I can go and execute some Query, so I think it is online.  How can I check in is online or not?

Comment: when you "login to sql server" (do you mean use of SSMS?), you use master database as your default database, here your code tries to open "database name" db that can be offline, suspect, restoring,...Try to change the code.var config = {
    server: "149.xxx.xx.x",
    database: "master",... and see if its connected

Comment: Or another reason can be that db is online, but you user just has no access to it

Comment: Ok, on master I put the console.log and it's Connected!

But I can't do my query on that:

`{ RequestError: Invalid object name 'nameofTable'.`

`name: 'RequestError',
  message: 'Invalid object name \'nameofTable\'.',
  code: 'EREQUEST',
  number: 208,
  lineNumber: 1,
  state: 1,
  class: 16,
  serverName: VPSNAME',
  procName: '',
  precedingErrors: [] }`

And yes, I am using the SSMS Microsoft SQL server Managment studio + DataGrip on Mac - I am using as default the same from the code - NOT master.

Ichecked also in Logins my user, default database is the same from code.

Comment: that was only a test that your program can connect. We still don't know if the db is not online or your user just is not mapped to it

Comment: to chek if your db is online, execute this in master: select name, user_access_desc, state_desc
from sys.databases
where name='yourDatabase'

Comment: I checked this.

`name: Database Name,
user_acess_desc: MULTI_USER,
status_desc: ONLINE,`

So it's seems to be online.

Comment: So maybe your User is not mapped to this databae. To check this run the code: select *
from yourDB.sys.database_principals
where name = 'YourUserName'

Comment: `(0 row(s) affected)`
Nothing is showing.

Comment: That is: your user has no access to this database. You should create the user and give him the permissions

Comment: The syntax is: use yourDB; create user YourUser from login YourUser; grant....

Comment: Could you write the exact code in `code` tag? I don't know which syntax should I use. Exactly what this syntax will do? I don't have permission for taking the data from the server? I am sure this login can add new records to the tables because we're using this credentials for another program.

Comment: See here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-user-transact-sql example A is your case, the login is already created you need only user

Comment: >>>I don't have permission for taking the data from the server?<<< you wrote "When I login in SQL Server or DataGrip I can go and execute some Query, so I think it is online" so you can execute something? Or your login is not that login which have a problem when connecting from your application? I mean, is the login is the same, do you use YOUR login in your program?

Comment: @sepupic Your advice working fine! **Thank you very much!** I spend on that few hours..

So, the problem was my user don't have permission to read the data from the database?

I think you can share this reply below (not as a comment) to everyone on future will know the answer!

Comment: The user was not even mapped to that database, but did you resolve your problem now? By creating the user and giving him the permissions?

Comment: Yes, the problem was resolved. Thank you, I am not familiar with databases at all (basically I am working in Front End side).

Comment: Ok, I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To find the reason of 18456 error "login failed for user..." one should check SQLServer error log.

In case of

> Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'Database
>   Name'

one should first check the state of the database, if it's online, like this:

```
 select name, 
       user_access_desc, 
       state_desc 
 from sys.databases where name='yourDatabase'
```

In case the database is online, the next step is to check is the user can access the database (if it's mapped to the database:)

```
 select * 
 from yourDB.sys.database_principals 
 where name = 'YourUserName';
```

This code is valid for checking existance of user corresponding to sql server login only (windows login can access the server using windows group login, so does the user)

In case the user does not exists we should create user for this login and give him appropriate permissions. Here is the link for user cteation 
[CREATE USER (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-user-transact-sql)